# Denying checkin permissions to a file for all users using TF.EXE

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, permissions

After building my installer I am checking it into TFS with a post-build batch file from VS using tf.exe. I would like to deny any further checkins for that file to every TFS user - including myself.

I am using "tf.exe permission /deny:checkin setup.exe".
However, I am required to add or /group or /user option.

Is there a way to allow all users? There seems to be no documented way which leads to me think I shouldn't be doing it in the first place?

I'm using hosted Team Services via visualstudio.com

Comment: You shouldn't be putting binaries or build outputs into source control.

Comment: You could use `Project Valid Users`

Comment: I agree with @daniel mann that putting binaries in source control is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking in the build outputs, you can consider making a project reference or create a NuGet package.

Regarding deny a permission for all users in a team project, you can use group **`Project Valid Users`**, which contains all users and groups that have been added anywhere within the team project. The full name of the group is `[{team project name}]/{group name}`.